# Need dynamic arraylist(Bitmap and 2 Strings) in a list array-Custom List Adapter

Tags: android, arraylist

I wanted to as if anyone knows a way to have 1 bitmap array and 2 String array combined to a list array. The bitmap and String array are created dynamically depending on the amount of image being taken. I have created something similar before with the following code but nothing with dynamic images or string. Since i am not well verse with Arrays, it would be really nice if someone can help with detail step. Really appreciate it.

I know it can take text but not sure how to go about convert the arraylist to add it as a string in the holder

ERROR LOG CAT-08-11 12:49:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(19906): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Main Activity

```
    private List<String> Titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> Actions = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Bitmap> Images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

  static int x;
      static int y=1;
      static int z=1;
      static int a=1;

while(y!=x){

                String comment = commentresult();

          //      pdf = new File(root);
                Titles.add(comment);
                y++;
                Log.d("y",new Integer(y).toString());
                }

            while(z!=x){

                String act = actionresult();
                Actions.add(act);
                z++;
                Log.d("z",new Integer(z).toString());}

            while(a!=x){
                Bitmap photo = getbitmap();
                Images.add(photo);
                a++;
                Log.d("a",new Integer(a).toString());}



            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
            RowItem item = new RowItem(Images, Titles,Actions);
            rowItems.add(item);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.aname_list_item, rowItems);        
        try {

        listView.setAdapter(adapter); **Getting Error On this Part**

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
          } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);}
    }
```

RowItems

```
           public class RowItem {
private List<Bitmap> imageId;
private List<String> title;
private List<String> desc;

public RowItem(List<Bitmap> images, List<String> titles, List<String> actions) {
    this.imageId = images;
    this.title = titles;
    this.desc = actions;
}
public List<Bitmap> getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
public void setImageId(List<Bitmap> imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
public List<String> getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(List<String> desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public List<String> getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(List<String> title) {
    this.title = title;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" + desc;
}
}
```

Custom List Adapter

```
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.aname_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rab);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtDesc.setText((CharSequence) rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText((CharSequence) rowItem.getTitle());
//  holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId()); **Need help with this**

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected behavior and what is actually happening?

Comment: it is giving me null point exception for adapter -  listView.setAdapter(adapter);. I wanted a way to have an image and 2 string which are in shared preference to show up in an array. Images and string does not have a definite number, the array fetches images based on users selection

Comment: Are you using the correct id for your list? Listview could be null because the view you specified couldn't be found.

Comment: id is correct. I feel it may be something within my custom adapter but not really sure as i am somewhat oblivious to array list/adapter.

Comment: I suspect what Nathan is suspecting: your listview is wrong. Put `Log.d("TAG", "listview null? " + (listView == null));`. It might be `android.R.id.list`.

Comment: for the TAG, it says listview null? True even though i put android.R.id.list. I checked there is a listview with id list.

Comment: fixed the null point issue now i have 08-11 12:49:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(19906): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence